# Java Instant.parse on Date java 8

Tags: java, time, kml, datetime-parsing, java-time

I have some legacy KML documents which includes a time stamp entry.
Why is the below date not valid when using Instant to parse? Both methods are suppose to parse ISO 8601 formatted dates.

String dateString =  "2017-12-04T08:06:60Z"

Using

```
java.time.Instant.parse(dateString)
```

throws an error

```
"DateTimeParseException Text 2017-12-04T08:06:60Z could not be parsed at index 0."
```

However, when using

```
Date myDate =   javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseDateTime( dateString )
```

myDate is parsed correctly....

Comment: 60 is not a valid number of seconds, is it? Also, class `java.util.Calendar` is lenient by default so I guess it accepts 60 seconds.

Comment: It can be for a leap second. But I don't *think* `java.time` supports leap seconds. (And I don't believe that's a valid leap second.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. `60` seconds isn't a valid time. Meaning that this is invalid `2017-12-04T08:06:60Z`, if it was 60 seconds then the minute should have incremented and *your* time would be `2017-12-04T08:07:00Z`
2. Using a valid date and then parsing the *String* would work just fine:

   ```
   String date = "2017-12-04T08:07:00Z";
   System.out.println(Instant.parse(date));
   ```

Also java.time ignores *leap* seconds. From the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html):

> Implementations of the Java time-scale using the JSR-310 API are not
>   required to provide any clock that is sub-second accurate, or that
>   progresses monotonically or smoothly. **Implementations are therefore
>   not required to actually perform the UTC-SLS slew or to otherwise be
>   aware of leap seconds**. JSR-310 does, however, require that
>   implementations must document the approach they use when defining a
>   clock representing the current instant. See Clock for details on the
>   available clocks.

Comment: "60 seconds isn't a valid time" - well, that all depends on your view of leap seconds. But I don't think *this particular* date/time is valid even if you include leap seconds, as that wasn't a time that a leap second was observed.

Comment: i get ya...but it seems like having 60Z is valid in the IISO 8601, and thus      javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter works and doesn't throw an exception...and automatically increments to 7:00Z.

Comment: There's no need to use a specific `DateTimeFormatter` for this pattern - `Instant.parse` is fine for ISO-8601 values with a "Z" zone offset.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Point taken. Thanks.

Comment: DatatypeConverter automatically increments the date...to 2017-12-04T08:07:00Z...ok. i am processing KML so can't adjust the data so will have to continue to use this class.

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer is fine. I just have two things to add:

1. You *can* parse the string with the invalid second value of 60 by using `ResolverStyle.LENIENT`.
2. Since Jon Skeet in a comment mentioned a possible leap second: It’s not a valid leap second. java.time does support the parsing of a (valid) leap second.

**Parsing your string**

```
    DateTimeFormatter lenientFormatter
            = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME
                    .withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.LENIENT);
    String dateString = "2018-12-04T08:06:60Z";
    Instant myInstant = lenientFormatter.parse(dateString, Instant::from);
    System.out.println(myInstant);
```

Output:

> 2018-12-04T08:07:00Z

So the overflowing second value of 60 has been rolled into a full minute.

By the way, `javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseDateTime` parses into a `Calendar` (not a `Date`), which is how the returned object can in fact hold a second value of 60. It seems that it generally accepts a second value of 60, but throws an exception on 61.

**Parsing a valid leap second**

This does in no way answer your question, but I thought that it might be useful for future readers. A leap second is always the last second of the day, so 23:59:60. An `Instant` cannot *hold* this value, but you can query whether one was parsed. It’s supported via `DateTimeFormatterBuilder.appendInstant(),` and `DateTimeFormatter.parsedLeapSecond()`.

```
    DateTimeFormatter leapSecondFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .appendInstant()
            .toFormatter();
    Instant myInstant
            = leapSecondFormatter.parse("2018-12-04T23:59:60Z", Instant::from);
    System.out.println(myInstant);

    TemporalAccessor parsed = leapSecondFormatter.parse("2018-12-04T23:59:60Z");
    System.out.println("Instant: " + parsed.query(Instant::from));
    System.out.println("Was a leap second parsed? "
            + parsed.query(DateTimeFormatter.parsedLeapSecond()));
```

Output:

> ```
> 2018-12-04T23:59:59Z
> Instant: 2018-12-04T23:59:59Z
> Was a leap second parsed? true
> ```

I don’t know why it had to be this complicated, but it works.

**Link:** [Documentation of `DateTimeFormatter.parsedLeapSecond`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#parsedLeapSecond--)