# How can I parse RFC 3339 date string into ZondeDateTime?

Tags: java, date, datetime, parsing, rfc3339

**Problem:**

I should parse an [RFC3339](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339) date string. It works fine with [ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME):

```
ZonedDateTime.parse("1985-04-12T23:20:50.52Z", ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME);
ZonedDateTime.parse("1996-12-19T16:39:57-08:00", ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME);
```

Let's say I'll fix a problem of Unknown Local Offset Convention just to not accept these dates.
But I still have a problem with some corner cases like this:

> ```
>   1990-12-31T23:59:60Z
> ```
>
> This represents the leap second inserted at the end of 1990.
>
> ```
>   1990-12-31T15:59:60-08:00
> ```
>
> This represents the same leap second in Pacific Standard Time, 8
> hours behind UTC."1990-12-31T15:59:60-08:00"

**Question:**

- How can I parse it avoiding to lose any seconds?

**Update:**

- Does it exist any alternative to ZonedDateTime that suits well
  RFC3339?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "avoiding losing any seconds"? I don't *think* java.time supports leap seconds, e.g. `ZonedDateTime.getSeconds()` is documented to return a value in the range 0-59 inclusive. Would you be happy with it returning midnight UTC at the start of 1991 instead?

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6038136/how-do-i-parse-rfc-3339-datetimes-with-java/71293847#71293847

Answer (score 2, accepted):

java.time doesn’t offer any direct support for what you want. Just earlier today I wrote [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55310635/5772882) that also has a section on parsing a leap second. But what is said there is all there is.

So there’s hand parsing left. I’d try something along these lines: Use a regular expression for detecting whether the second is 60. If so: Substitute it with 59. Parse. Convert to UTC. If the time of day in UTC is 23:59:59, assume there was a valid leap second in the original string; otherwise the string didn’t denote a valid time.

I suggest that in case of a leap second second values up to 60.999999999 are valid. So to detect whether there is a 60 you need to look at what comes after the colon (if any) after the minutes, and not depend on whether there is a fractional part too.